# Defining variables depending on the target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I've got a Makefile that looks like:

```
gator: LIB=-lm
gatorgpu : GPU=-DG

 ....
STATIC=
ifdef STATIC
  $(info CPU static)    
endif
```

But I would like to have something like:

```
gator: LIB=-lm
gatorgpu : GPU=-DG

 ....
STATIC=
ifdef STATIC
   ifdef GPU
     $(info GPU static) 
   else
    $(info CPU static)
   endif
 endif
```

So when somebody types `$make gatorgpu STATIC=1` or `$make gator STATIC=1` then it will compile with static libraries depending on the target, in this case CPU or GPU. Unfortunatelly, `STATIC` is read however `GPU` variables is not, so it always goes for`CPU static`. Is there an elegant way of doing it?

Comment: The thing you're missing is that target-specific variables are only in effect _while make is building that target_.  So testing `GPU` in a global scope like an `ifdef` won't work, since it's not defined until later when make starts building the `gatorgpu` target.

Comment: @MadScientist I see the problem, target-specific variables cannot be used for this purpose. But what could I do instead? How can I define a variable depending on the target ?

Comment: Well, your question is simply too abstract for us to advise you effectively.  It's good to create a cut-down version of your makefile BUT you must be careful you don't cut it so far that all the context is lost.  Presumably you want to do _something_, besides run `$(info ...)`, depending on the GPU type.  Without knowing more about what that something is we can't give you advice on the best way to do it, other than by guessing at solutions until something works.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target specific variables are only available within the corresponding recipes for a reason. Different targets can use a different version of the same variable for its recipe.

Although if you decide to use target specific variables to achieve whatever you're tyring to do, this would work:

```
gator: export LIB := -lm
gatorgpu : export GPU := -DG
STATIC ?= 0
ACTUAL ?= 0

export STATIC

ifeq ($(ACTUAL),1)
ifeq ($(STATIC), 1)
    ifneq ($(GPU),)
        $(info GPU static) 
    else
        $(info CPU static)
    endif
endif
endif

.gator:
    @echo LIB=$(LIB) GPU=$(GPU)

.gatorgpu:
    @echo LIB=$(LIB) GPU=$(GPU)

gator:
    @$(MAKE) .gator ACTUAL=1

gatorgpu:
    @$(MAKE) .gatorgpu ACTUAL=1

PHONY: .gator .gatorgpu gator gatorgpu
```

- This has the overhead of invoking an additional make (per target) with the correct set of exported variables.
- The export ensures that the variables are set for any sub-processes run from `make`.

This is the result I see:

```
$ make gatorgpu
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ash/.scratch/make-test'
LIB= GPU=-DG
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ash/.scratch/make-test'

$ make gator
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ash/.scratch/make-test'
LIB=-lm GPU=
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ash/.scratch/make-test'

$ make gatorgpu STATIC=1
GPU static
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ash/.scratch/make-test'
LIB= GPU=-DG
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ash/.scratch/make-test'

$ make gator STATIC=1
CPU static
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ash/.scratch/make-test'
LIB=-lm GPU=
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ash/.scratch/make-test'
```

A couple of minor corrections, although it does not impact the results much:

- The `?=` (known as [`conditional variable assignment operator`](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_toc.html#TOC64)) performs the assignment only when the variable is unassigned. So when you run `make mytarget STATIC=1`, the variable STATIC would not be assigned `0`.
- `ifeq` and `ifneq` are more robust check compared to `ifdef`, as you can compare the variable against a specific value you're interested in.
- `:=` should be preferred over the regular `=` to avoid unnecessary slowdown in make, unless you really have a need for [`recursively expanded variables`](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_toc.html#TOC59).

A better approach would be to refactor your Makefile such a way that you define different target-specific variables or rules just based on the value of `STATIC`

```
ifeq ($(STATIC), 1)
gator: LIB := -lm
gatorgpu : GPU := -DG
else
gator: LIB := <SOMETHING_ELSE_HERE>
gatorgpu : GPU := <SOMETHING_ELSE_HERE>
endif
```

There is also a not-so-recommended approach that involves checking the value of `$(MAKECMDGOALS)`, which contains the target with which make was invoked.

```
ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),gatorgpu)
    GPU := -DG
endif
```

Comment: @ Tuxdude I've tried what you suggested, but GPU variable is still not defined by the time Makefile reaches the `ifeq` section...

Comment: @Manolete - Have updated the answer, the initial question was not so clear the first time :)

Comment: @ Tuxdude I like the `$(MAKECMDGOALS)` approach. Why do you think it is not-so recommended?

Answer (score 1):

From your description, I would say the following approach can be used:

```
ifdef STATIC
gator: LIB:=-static -lstaticlib
gatorgpu: GPU:=-DSTATICDEF
else
gator: LIB:=-lm
gatorgpu: GPU:=-DG
endif
```

You have not exactly stated what options you want to use or change in the case when `STATIC` is defined versus when it is not defined, so I have made up some example values.